# Grayscale images causing slideToggle to break

Tags: jquery, css

I have a vertical slider that contains 4 images. Each image is set as grayscale until the "down" button is clicked and they become coloured again. However, the `.slideToggle` function 'stutters' or breaks after the "down" button is pressed again.

Here is a snippet of the jQuery

```
var count = 1;
var number = 1;

$("#number").text("0"+number+"/04");
$("#down").click(function(){
    if(count==1){
        $("#1").slideToggle();
        $('#gallery ul li:nth-child(2)').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
        count = 2;
        number = 2;
        $("#number").text("0"+number+"/04");
    }
    else if(count==2){
        $("#2").slideToggle();
        $('#gallery ul li:nth-child(3)').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
        count = 3;
        number = 3;
        $("#number").text("0"+number+"/04");
    }
    else if(count==3){
        $("#3").slideToggle();
        $('#gallery ul li:nth-child(4)').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
        count = 4;
        number = 4;
        $("#number").text("0"+number+"/04");
    }
    else if(count==4){
        count = 4;
        number = 4;
        $("#number").text("0"+number+"/04");
    }
})
```

Here is my [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RArnone/r4mq41c4/15/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont exactly know what are looking for,but i think in your code the slideToggle will not work from 2nd `li` because they are already placed vertically below each other and the slideToggle and hiding of the `li` wont work i guess.

Now i have a alternative, if you dont mind chaning the code a little.Use the `animate` function like this:

```
    $("#2").animate({'margin-top':'-309px'}); /***CHANGE FIX PIXEL VALUE TO YOUR PX OR % VALUE***/
```

Just check this fiddle link for the working https://jsfiddle.net/r4mq41c4/23/
Let me know for any changes!

Comment: Awesome thanks! This works great. Is there a way to make this responsive? If the images scale with the window is there a way for the `.animate margin-top` value to change as well?

Comment: It should be possible if you use % 's instead of pixels i guess? Could you give it a try...

Comment: It works but it's very unpredictable...that's alright though. they're just going to be thumbnails anyways. I'll just scale them down to fit all sizes. Thanks Varun. By any chance, do you know how to use '%' in jquery when styling css?

Comment: In the fiddle all images are of different sizes,hence there maybe some issue but you can use % values just like the px values in jquery animate.

Comment: I should probably start a new question for this but when I click the "up" arrow and the `margin-top` is set back to 0, how can I reverse the `.css("-webkit-filter", "none");` so that the image becomes black and white again?

Comment: Ah! I was making such a dumb mistake. Thank you!